# Ruby on Rails: undefined method in my view partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, undefined

I get this error: `undefined method 'vote_sum' for nil:NilClass`

for this line in my view partial: `<p id='votes'><%= pluralize @video.vote_sum, 'Votes' %></p>`

I don't understand why since `vote_sum` is a column in the videos table. Here's some of the relevant logic in my `Video` model:

```
def vote_sum
  read_attribute(:vote_sum) || video_votes.sum(:value)
end
```

and my `VideoVote` model:

```
after_create :update_vote_sum

private

  def update_vote_sum
    video.update_attributes(:vote_sum => video.vote_sum + value)
  end
```

Any understanding of why `@video.vote_sum` is undefined in my view partial?

UPDATE:

Here's the relevant code in the create method of my video_votes controller:

```
  @video = Video.find(params[:video_vote][:video_id])
  @vote = @video.video_votes.new
```

Comment: you sure @video is being defined in your controller? Can you add the controller code and the view that calls the partial?

Comment: I posted the relevant code from the video_votes controller. I dont think the view that renders the partial is relevant, but the view that renders the partial is another partial that is located in the video directory within the views directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is saying vote_sum is an undefined method because it isn't calling it on a video, it is actually calling it on Nil. This is happening because @video is nil, rather than being an instance of Video.

The problem is that @video isn't being set properly in your controller.

I think you want

```
@video = Video.find(params[:video_id])
```

assuming params[:video_id] exists.

**Edit**

It seems as though you have a list of videos you want to show a partial for, and rails provides a mechinism for showing a collection of partials.

```
<%= render @videos %> # assuming you have a partial called _video.html.erb
```

To access the video, you access it using the `video` variable in _video.html.erb

See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) for more.

Comment: This is currently in my video_votes controller: `@video = Video.find(params[:video_vote][:video_id])`
   `@vote = @video.video_votes.new` This isn't correct?

Comment: Yes, and that line is wrong somehow because it is setting @video to nil

Comment: Ohhh, maybe it's because this partial is being rendered in my index view, and this is what I have in the index method in my video controller: `@videos = Video.all` How can I fix this?

Comment: yeah, I see your new solution. I actually created a new partial and rendered the partial in the _video.html.erb partial. I

Comment: Yup, and that worked. I was making it unneccessarily difficult by rendering a partial in a partial...

Comment: i am doing <% \@flash = flash %>  <%= render 'layouts/flash' %> and it works, but i tried <%= render \@flash %> and it doesn't how can I achieve it?
(omit the \, it is to avoid SO to try to tag someone)